# If arriving at Heathrow from a non-exempt country, what are the options for getting from the airport to your quarantine location in London?

Tags: uk, covid-19, lhr, quarantine

If arriving at Heathrow from a non-exempt country, what are the options for getting from the airport to your quarantine location in London?

Taxi? Uber? Public transport?

Answer (score 2):

From [the government guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk/coronavirus-covid-19-how-to-self-isolate-when-you-travel-to-the-uk):

> When you arrive in the UK, go straight to the place you’re staying.
>
> Only use public transport if you have no other option. If you do use public transport, wear something that covers your nose and mouth and stay 2 metres apart from other people. Pack a face covering or scarf to cover your nose and mouth before you travel. If you have coronavirus symptoms, you will not be allowed to travel by public transport and will need to demonstrate that the accommodation where you will self-isolate is safe.

Comment: Yes. That's the government guidance. How might we apply it to my question? '2m apart' what a joke.

Comment: @Strawberry The source directly answers your question...

Comment: I would be curious to see how one would take the London tube while staying 2m away from others :)

Comment: @Strawberry In reality, no need to be overthinking this; just keep your distance to the extent possible.

Comment: And better use a proper face mask if you fear keeping distance is impossible, not just a scarf.

Comment: My friend took the black cab and paid the driver cash.

Comment: Black cab is a good choice, because the driver and passenger compartments are partitioned off from each other, reducing risk of infecting the driver.

Comment: @JonathanReez I took the Piccadilly and Victoria lines into/out of Central London last weekend, on a Saturday morning (so not a weekday rush-hour). The Piccadilly was about 10-15 people/carriage, the Victoria about 15-20 - it's closer to 1m than 2m separation in places, but it's a lot less crowded than you might expect!